# Tesseract OCR can't recognize basic alphanumeric codes

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Tesseract seems to have problems recognizing basic alphanumeric codes. I've tried upscaling the image, changing to a monospace font and turning off the dictionary with no improvement in OCR quality.

The image below is recognized as the following:

i3DOIIH_My ActivitiesJ

MmRSes_My Accounm DBYCAe_My Submissions1

Hrti6_My Renewam

[image]

As you can see the recognized characters are completely off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original image size is `1508 x 1092 pixels` with 4 lines plus vertical spacing, it seems too big.

After reduced the image to `503 x 364 pixels`, around `76 pixels` height for the characters. 
[image]

Tesseract gives 100% OCR result on the text.
[image]

The font size and background color do affect the OCR result. The best result would be obtained from text in black-in-white. Otherwise, image preprocessing is likely required.

Hope this help.

Comment: Does tesseract not do preprocessing to make the image black and white automatically?

Comment: @MichaelStudebaker From this paper - [An Overview of the Tesseract OCR Engine](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/docs/blob/master/tesseracticdar2007.pdf), tesseract assumes the input is a binary image with optional polygonal text regions defined. It does perform  preprocessing to align, find and chop the text line, etc but not on binarization.

Comment: @MichaelStudebaker Does my reply answered your question? If not, any feedback to tell what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

Train tesseract for these type of characters including special characters.Refer this [Tesseract Training](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract)